# Excel Named Range Change Event

Tags: vba, excel

I want to monitor changes in a number of named ranges whose values change according to formulae and not user input so the `worksheet_change` event doesn't work for me.

Is it possible to do the equivalent of the following C# code in VBA?

```
range.Change += new DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler((Range Target) => {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: How does `selection_change` help?

Comment: Yeah, if you have no user intervention then its tricky. Selection change is of no use then.

Comment: Thx. Feel free to answer below and I'll accept.

Comment: One very crude method would be to run an infinite loop with doevents, check cell values, store immediate previous values, in case of change fire your routine. But it will be slow and if you have a lot of data it will be super slow. I am on mobile so no sample code.

Comment: No worries. I don't have to keep track of that many so I'll just store the previous values and only take action (via `Workbook_SheetCalculate`) if the new current value changes. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh... That's a perfect solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Name.Comment` property to store the old values.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    With ThisWorkbook
        If .Names("SumOfNumbers").Comment <> Range("SumOfNumbers").Value Then
            Debug.Print "SumOfNumbers has changed", .Names("SumOfNumbers").Comment, Range("SumOfNumbers").Value
            .Names("SumOfNumbers").Comment = Range("SumOfNumbers").Value
        End If

        If .Names("CountOfNumbers").Comment <> Range("CountOfNumbers").Value Then
            Debug.Print "CountOfNumbers has changed", .Names("CountOfNumbers").Comment, Range("CountOfNumbers").Value
            .Names("CountOfNumbers").Comment = Range("CountOfNumbers").Value
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own name handler which raised an event when the evaluated value changed.

In overview, you'd insert a new class (I've called it `NamesHandler`) with something like the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event ValueChanged(sender As Name)
Private WithEvents mApp As Application
Private mOldValues As Collection

Private Sub mApp_AfterCalculate()
    Dim n As Name
    Dim oldVal As Variant
    Dim newVal As Variant

    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        oldVal = Empty
        On Error Resume Next
        oldVal = mOldValues(n.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not IsEmpty(oldVal) Then
            newVal = Evaluate(n.Value)
            If newVal <> oldVal Then
                mOldValues.Remove n.Name
                mOldValues.Add newVal, n.Name
                RaiseEvent ValueChanged(n)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim n As Name
    Dim oldVal As Variant

    Set mApp = Application
    Set mOldValues = New Collection

    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        oldVal = Evaluate(n.Value)
        mOldValues.Add oldVal, n.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

You could then consume the event in, say, your Workbook code:

```
Private WithEvents mNamesHandler As NamesHandler

Private Sub mNamesHandler_ValueChanged(sender As Name)
    Debug.Print sender.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set mNamesHandler = New NamesHandler
End Sub
```